# Firefox "cookies" will not work

Tags: firefox

For example, after I login to superuser.com, exit the browser, and come back in...no cookies.
I cannot save my logins!

I have checked tools > options > privacy...and changed all the settings, but it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same kind of issues. I turned out the file storing the cookies was "corrupted". I remove it and restarted Firefox and it could save the cookies again.

The file is called cookies.sqllite. You'll find it on Vista and Windows 7 at the following location:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\
```

On Windows 2000 and XP it's located at:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\
```

I removed also the other file cookies.sqllite-journal.

Answer (score 3):

Check your **Options**, **Privacy** tab and make sure **Automatically start Firefox in a private browsing session** is not checked and you are accepting cookies from the sites you want to and that the **Keep until** option is not set to Keep until I close Firefox.

For me just checking **Accept cookied from sites** is enough to remember my login on superuser.